# Why is this transaction referred to as "low fee"?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

Why does Blockchain.info refer to [this](https://blockchain.info/tx/ff003a7ca895c3eb7148861ebb200551a310a71c99d50d5f69147969e91e08ee) transaction as "low fee", when it has the normal fee? What is wrong with it? Its size is less than 1000 bytes, with a fee of 0.1 mBTC – yet, this transaction just got stuck?

Could anyone please explain please what happened and why it got stuck?

Comment: Finally it confirmed. But confirmation time for only one confirmation took almost 24 hours. I never faced case like this before.

Answer (score 3):

It is 1343 bytes, larger than 1000 bytes, so you should have paid 0.2mBTC.

You have too many inputs in this transactions. If you had used a compressed public key, you might be able to save some bytes and shrink the transaction size down to under 1kB.